# Counting lines displayed by richtextbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

In my project I want to count lines displayed by richtextbox in C# with word wrap property set true. For example, in richtextbox, I write a text, and when text reaches the width of the richtextbox, then it automatically goes to second line. So what happens is the text contains actually one line but it is displayed in two lines. So I want to know how can I count this as two lines instead of one? Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You may go for [`RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx)

> Retrieves the line number from the
>   specified character position within
>   the text of the RichTextBox control. If `WordWrap` is set to `false`, no portion of the line wraps to the next, and the method returns 0 for the specified character index.

Also, check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/numberedtextbox.aspx).

Comment: No, you didn't get it. I want to set richtextbox1.wordwrap = true, and I want to count the lines in which that text is displayed. eg. "jjkvbhjkbjbfvbh kjvbhfvbkfvgbhj kjfhbhjmnbfjkbfvgbhfvghj jhbvjmnkkvjbvhjhb", this is such a long string and lets say it will not come in one row in Richtextbox,(maybe two, 3 rows). So, I want to count those rows instead of line(which is actually one).

Comment: @Shashank Please re-read the answer. It is precisely what you seek. It is meaningless unless `wordwrap == true`.

Comment: Yaa it worked. I used this command int lineNumber = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength) + 1; to get number of lines displayed by richtextbox. Thanks for the help.